# Displaying table and data in database doesnt show

Tags: php, mysql

i have this problem that my table doesnt show and all info in my database doesnt show also can you help me? the output only shows "Student No.  First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Subject Code    Units   Final
..." . my info in database doesnt show and the table I created didnt show also . Any answers how to fix this code? thankss

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "tsukishiro";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student_grades WHERE Student_ID='c2011-02529' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Student No.</th><th>First Name</th><th>Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Subject Code</th><th>Units</th><th>Final Grade</th><th>Remarks</th><th>Professor</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$Student_ID = $row['Student_ID'];
$First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
$Middle_Name = $row['Middle_Name'];
$Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
$Subject_Code = $row['Subject_Code'];
$Units = $row['Units'];
$Final_Grade = $row['Final_Grade'];
$Remarks = $row['Remarks'];
$Professor = $row['Professor'];

echo "<tr><td>".$Student_ID."</td><td>".$First_Name."</td><td>".$Middle_Name."</td><td>".$Last_Name."</td><td>".$Subject_Code."</td><td>".$Units."</td><td>".$Final_Grade."</td><td>".$Remarks."</td><td>".$Professor."</td></tr>";

} 
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
?>
```

this is`<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing ='2'><tr><td>Student No.</td><td>First Name</td><td>Middle Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Subject Code</td><td>Units</td><td>Final</td></tr></table>... </div>`
thats the only code in that page only

Comment: Have you checked page source to check what was output by PHP to rule out a display issue?  Also try print_r($row); or var_dump($row);  Also, you don't need to concatenate the variables, you can do like echo "<tr><td>$Student_ID</td></tr>";  It makes it more readable.

Comment: You're not catching any query errors, perhaps there is a problem with the query. Or it could be the student id doesn't exist.

Comment: the student id exist in my table and i dont know why my tables info didnt show up :(
@xeridea i check it and i just see only html codes help me sorry im really new in php and mysqli :/

Comment: You might try taking the  WHERE clause out of your query and seeing if you get results. This would indicate that your query string is subtly mismatching your stored data.

Comment: Try to check the $result value, if it is `false` or any result set. If `false` use mysqli_error function `mysqli_error($conn)` to check out errors.

Comment: I remove the where still only the html codes are showing i dont think my query mismatching my stored data because it runs(not white page) but the info didnt show up only "..."

Comment: Are you sure php is running on your server and that your file has an extension of .php. Can you also view source in your browser and post the results?

Comment: `<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing ='2'><tr><td>Student No.</td><td>First Name</td><td>Middle Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Subject Code</td><td>Units</td><td>Final</td></tr></table>... </div>` this is the code

Comment: @Roy Not sure that the source you're showing is actually from the file in your original question. There are some things in the show source display that flat out don't exist in your code sample.

Comment: @bigscar the only problem now is the where clause where i cant specify grade from others :((